# CSS: How do I select an element that is the first-of-type of one of the ancestors(not direct parent)?

Tags: css, selector

```html
<article>
  <div>
    Video
  </div>
  <div>
    Image
  </div>
  <div class="couldBeOtherWrappersLikeOL">
    <p class="howDoISelectThisPOnly">
      First paragraph
    </p>
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li>first point</li>
    <p>
      description of first point
    </p>
    <li>second point</li>
    <p>
      description of second point
    </p>
  </ol>
</article>
```

I want to make sure the first `P` in the article to be selected. Using

```
article p:first-of-type
```

is no good because this will also select the first `P` in the `OL` block. So how do I select the first occurrence of `P` in `ARTICLE`?

Comment: Unfortunately this remains impossible in CSS, and would - unfortunately - require JavaScript.